Jackson deserialize polymorphic type when value is primitive OR array
I have a JSON structure from a third party not under my control that I need to deserialize. One section contains a list of operands where the type is determined by the key, e.g. "variable" or "value".
{
  "operands": [
    {
      "variable": "a"
    },
    {
      "value": 42
    }
  ]
}

I found examples of this using @JsonTypeInfo on StackOverflow which were extremely helpful and worked perfectly at first, until I realized the value may be a primitive OR A LIST.
For example I'm not sure how to properly deserialize this:
{
  "operands": [
    {
      "variable": "manager"
    },
    {
      "value": ["bob", "alice"]
    }
  ]
}

Here's my original code which worked perfectly fine for primitives, but fails for a List of primitives:
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyValue.class, name = "value"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MyVariable.class, name = "variable")})
public interface MyOperand {}

public class MyValue implements MyOperand {

    private Object value;

    public MyValue(Integer value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MyValue(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public MyValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

The error I get is:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `org.acme.MyValue` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (String)"{ "operands": [
 { "variable": "a" },
 { "value": [42] }

I thought I could simply change private Object value to private List<Object> value and enable DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY to handle the case where I get a single value, but I receive the same error as above. I'm not sure how to proceed. Any ideas?

For some reason I was fixated on operands being polymorphic. A very simple workaround was to just use a single class:
public class MyOperand {
    private String variable;
    private Object value;
}

And then I added a method:
public OperandType getType() {
  if (variable != null) {
     return OperandType.VARIABLE;
  }
  if (value != null) {
     return OperandType.VALUE;
  }
  ...
}

May not be ideal but it works.
